# Warning in installation process

Tags: magento2, error, fatal-error

**Getting Error**

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 70

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor/magento/zendframework1/library;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Comment: Hi, how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Error looks like you have not installed PHP mbstring or wrong version. You can install it by following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

Now restart the Apache.
Also check if composer is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. it requires php extension named "mbstring"

install PHP-mbstring extension on your server, if you are using M2 on local than run below CMD..

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

change PHP version on above CMD acording to which u's using..
and restart you apache2.

let me know is it working for anyOne or not..  THANK YOU!